# Unable to extracting a substring from an NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have an input string in the format

"Jerry Lane"(angle bracket)jerry.lane@gmail.com(bracket closed),"Harry Potter"(angle bracket)harry.potter@gmail.com(bracket closed),"Indiana Jones",(angle bracket)indiana.jones@gmail.com(bracket closed),"Tom Cruise"(angle bracket)tom.cruise@gmail.com(bracket closed)

Here, i am supposed to first separate the string on the basis of comma delimiter, which would give me a separate string like

"Jerry Lane"(angle bracket)jerry.lane@gmail.com(bracket closed)

Then i need to save extract the string between the <> brackets, which is essentially the string "jerry.lane@gmail.com". I am using the following code, but it is giving me the following error:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString substringWithRange:]: Range or index out of bounds'**

```
-(NSArray *)parseString:(NSString *)string
{
  if(string)
  {
    NSArray *myArray = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    for(NSMutableString *myString in myArray)
    {
        NSRange start,end;
        start = [myString rangeOfString:@"<"];
        end = [myString rangeOfString:@">"];
        if(start.location != NSNotFound && end.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            NSString *emailAddress = [myString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(start.location,end.location)];
            NSString *name = [myString substringToIndex:start.location];

            NSDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
            [myDictionary setValue:emailAddress forKey:@"Dhruvil Vyas"];
            [testArray addObject:myDictionary];

        }
    }
}

return testArray;
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arguments that substring takes are the start position and the **length**

Not the start position and the end position.

[More Info](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSRange)

Comment: Just to make it really explicit: You need to subtract the start from the end to get the length of the substring.

Answer (score 1):

borrrden's answer is correct. Here is another way to do this.

```
-(NSArray *)parseString:(NSString *)string
{
  if(string)
  {
    NSArray *myArray = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    for(NSMutableString *myString in myArray)
    {
        NSArray *tempNameArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"<"];
        NSString *email = [tempNameArray objectAtIndex:1];

        NSArray *tempMailArray = [email componentsSeparatedByString:@">"];

        NSString *emailAddress = [tempMailArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *name = [tempNameArray objectAtIndex:0];

        NSDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
        [myDictionary setValue:emailAddress forKey:@"Dhruvil Vyas"];
        [testArray addObject:myDictionary];
    }
  }

 return testArray;
}
```

Comment: If you wanna get extra points, then instead of this use `NSScanner` :)